# MySQL SUM all orders by distinct classification of order items

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I am sorry if my question is not very descriptive. Will update later when I get better idea.

I would like to create SQL that SUM's me order totals by classification of it's order items.

To make things simple I have made stripped down version of my schema which I have loaded here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8eb9a/1. My table structure:

- **orders**: id, total
- **order_items**: id, order_id, data

Each order item has a data field that classifies order item into certain category. Can be for example "Automotive", "DSA", ... or null. Now I would like to SUM(orders.total) by each of these classifiers. If order item fits into "Automotive" classifier I would like to add order's total into that classifier. If order has another item, for example "DSA" I would like to add order's total also into that classifier.

I tried running this SQL but this does not SUM right, because if order has more then one order item with the same classifier it add's multiple order's totals for that classifier (LEFT JOIN)...

```
select OI.data, SUM(O.total)
from order_items OI 
left join orders O on O.id=OI.order_id
group by data
```

I would like to add order total only once for every order to the each of distinct order item classifiers.

You can see the example in this SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8eb9a/1

Comment: Could you post some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: Why do you need `LEFT JOIN`? Can an `order_item` refer to a nonexistent `order`?

Comment: @Barmar nope it cant... I have referred SQL fiddle with some data...

Comment: Then you should use `INNER JOIN`. But I don't think it makes a difference to your question.

Comment: sqlfiddle shows the data, it doesn't show the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to add distinct rows based on your description:

```
select OI.data, SUM(O.total)
from (SELECT DISTINCT order_id,data FROM order_items) OI 
left join orders O on O.id=OI.order_id
group by data;
```